# Run Method Certain Time, Day, Year (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logic, message

I am writing a ruby program that will ask a user a to type a message, then a year, month, day and time and then email a message when that time comes. I store that data into a database table. The program should loop until that day comes and then carry out the sending.

Without using a database, I have written the following:

```
def send_Message(m_to, m_from, m_body, month, day, year, hour, min)
x = 0
t = Time.now


if (t.day == day 
    && t.month == month 
    && t.year == year 
    && t.strftime("%I") == hour 
    && t.strftime("%M") == min )

    x = x +5

    message = @client.account.sms.messages.create(:body => m_body,
        :to => m_to,
        :from => m_from)
    puts message.sid   

else
    sleep_time = Time.new(year,month,day)
    total_sleep = sleep_time - t
    sleep(total_sleep)
    message = @client.account.sms.messages.create(:body => m_body,
        :to => m_to,
        :from => m_from)
    puts message.sid  
end

end
```

but it only really seems to work with the month, day, year thing, but not time. There are two questions I am seeking an answer to: how can I carry out  looping through a database, seeking chronologically messages to send, and with my example code above, how can I use the hour and minute of the day along with the day month and year to send the message.

P.S: I am designing this app on over to rails, where a user/app sends an API request and then the process I mentioned will be carried out.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to not run the Ruby program until the time comes that you want to run it?  Look at the scheduling tools for your operating system.  `at` or `cron` may be just the thing for you.

Comment: The thing is, I should have mentioned it, I'm going to move this on to rails, where users can send an API request and the server will record the data I spoke about and execute what I spoke about

Comment: Edit the question and retag it to include Rails, you will get a Rails-centric answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few approaches:
Look into the gem whenever

```
 gem install whenever
```

https://github.com/javan/whenever

It doesn't do exactly what you asked but it is much better than running ruby for 6 month's waiting for an email to be sent.

**An even better approach is resque**  https://github.com/defunkt/resque

Then add https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler and your solution is very nice without the drag of a million ruby instances waiting to send an email.

Good Luck...

BTW:  I made a service to do exactly what you are asking.  I have specs and the code.  If you want I can get it to you.

Comment: I would love if you could do that :)

Comment: Look at my email on my account I believe it is public.

Comment: its no there. but my email is galiro at galiro dot com